# Flutter translate filter with parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, translation, intl

I'm trying to translate an string like "filter [solved|date] clear". If I don't want to translate the parameters (solved|date), all works well.

```
MyLocalizations.of(context).clearFilter( filter.activeFilter)
```

But i want to translate the parameters, too. Because it's not possible do access the object properties dynamically, to following doesn't work:

```
MyLocalizations.of(context).clearFilter( MyLocalizations.of(context)[filter.activeFilter] )
```

I didn't find any examples :-( But I hope anybody can help me.

Best,
Dominik

// edit:
// the filter [solved|date] could be "solved" or "date"

Answer (score 0):

In `MyLocalizations`, the translations should look like this:

```
String clearFilter(String value) => Intl.message("filter $value clear",
  args: [value],
  name: "clearFilter",
  desc: "clearFilter");

String get activeFilter => Intl.message("[solved|date]",
  name: "activeFilter",
  desc: "activeFilter");
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
MyLocalizations.of(context).clearFilter(MyLocalizations.of(context).activeFilter)
```

Take a look at the README file of intl package: https://github.com/dart-lang/intl#messages